# Date in Complete form

Tags: freepascal

I have really no idea what codes to use to this program: Write a program that accepts dates written in numerical form and then output them as a complete form. For example: The input is 2 26 1986 the output should be February 26, 1986.

Answer (score 2):

That's basically an oneliner:

```
uses dateutils,sysutils;
var s :string;

begin
  s:='2 26 1986';
  // readln(s);
  writeln(formatdatetime('mmmm d, yyyy',scandatetime('m d yyyy',s)));
end.
```

It assumes an English locale though, which you can forceload (under Windows) with getlocaleformatsettings in newer FPCs. Or load your own formatsettings, formatdatetime has an overloaded version for custom formatsettings.